# Out of memory exception using gson + volley when doing gson.fromJson();

Tags: android, gson, android-volley, android-networking

I am reading a very large json file using volley and gson.. I'v seen that I need to use an input stream to overcome this but how do I create a input stream from the network response?

I'v pasted the gson request class which is getting the response from the get request

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T[]> {

private final Gson gson;
private final Class<T[]> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Listener<T[]> listener;

public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T[]> clazz,
        Map<String, String> headers, Listener<T[]> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);

    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

    this.gson = gsonBuilder.create();
    this.clazz = clazz;
    this.headers = headers;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T[] response) {
    listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T[]> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {

        String json = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        // Log.e("Response", json.toString());
        T[] t = gson.fromJson(json, clazz);

        return Response.success(t,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "UnsupportedEncodingException");

        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "JsonSyntaxException");

        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }

}
```

}

My json data format

```
[
   {
        "salary": "Best In Industry",
        "companyProfile": "string",
        "tags": [
            "mtech"
        ],
    }, {
        "salary": "Best In Industry",
        "companyProfile": "string",
        "tags": [     
            "be/btech",
        ],
     }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reads Example**
This code reads a JSON document containing an array of messages. It steps through array elements as a stream to avoid loading the complete document into memory. It is concise because it uses Gson’s object-model to parse the individual messages:

```
public List<Message> readJsonStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    reader.beginArray();
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        Message message = gson.fromJson(reader, Message.class);
        messages.add(message);
    }
    reader.endArray();
    reader.close();
    return messages;
}
```

**Writes Example**

Mirroring the code above, this writes a JSON document containing an array of messages. It benefits from the memory-efficiency of streaming and the conciseness of an object model:

```
public void writeJsonStream(OutputStream out, List<Message> messages) throws IOException {
    JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"));
    writer.setIndent("  ");
    writer.beginArray();
    for (Message message : messages) {
        gson.toJson(message, Message.class, writer);
    }
    writer.endArray();
    writer.close();
}
```

Refrence link https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

Comment: Hey Thanks!
I have seen this but how do i create a input stream from the response.

Comment: This is basically for array response. what json structure you have?

Comment: So, the main thing is don't use string to bind response. You have a JsonArray with you that is similar to List<Message> messages, in writeJsonStream() method.Make a model to parse JsonObject at array index and replace it with Message.class

Comment: How do i store the response if i do not bind it to a string

Comment: You have to forget the approach you are using.Carefully read the link i have attached from the first line.you were doing Object model access but now we have to stream access. Study what the readJsonStream() do. Just spend some time on it and i am sure you will get the solution in that post.